# locationmanager.requestForLocation is not working in motorola backflip & samsung galaxy

Tags: android, gps

I am newbie in Android, I am trying to retrieve the GPS data in my application.
   I am using following code
`LocationManager lm = (LocationManager) getSystemService(Context.LOCATION_SERVICE);`

```
if (!lm.isProviderEnabled(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER)){
  lm.requestLocationUpdates(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER, 1000L, 500.0f, this);
}
```

And my class I have overriden the following method

```
public void onLocationChanged(Location location)
{
  String currentLocation = "The location is changed to Lat: " + location.getLatitude()+ " Lng: " + location.getLongitude();
  Toast.makeText(context, currentLocation, Toast.LENGTH_LONG);
}
```

But it is not showing anything and this is happening only with motorola **backflip & samsung galaxy devices**.
   Please let me know if I am doing anything wrong. Thanks in advance.

Thansk,
Devanand

Answer (score 3):

You forgot to use Toast.makeText(...)**.show();**

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure this code shows something for other phones? As Neeraj answered, you have to add .show() to the Toast.

If that is not an issue & you just missed it here, then you might have come across a problem I was facing too. A piece of code similar to yours worked perfectly on **Motorola Atrix**, but not on **Motorola Droid**.

**Here was my workaround. In case GPS is not available, I fall back on the Network provider**. Like so:

```
//Start with fine location using GPS
String locationProviderInit = LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER;
if ((locationProviderInit == null) ||   
      !(mLocationManager.isProviderEnabled(locationProviderInit)))
{
//If GPS not available, fall back on coarse location
    locationProviderInit = LocationManager.NETWORK_PROVIDER;
}
```

Hope this helps!