# Getting location in android not working on newer device

Tags: java, android

I am trying to find the current location in my project.So i found this post:

[What is the simplest and most robust way to get the user's current location on Android?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3145089/what-is-the-simplest-and-most-robust-way-to-get-the-users-current-location-in-a)

I tried using locationclient but was not satisfied with the result.The code that i have used is as follows:

The Mylocation.java class:

```
package com.igloo.classes;

import java.util.Timer;
import java.util.TimerTask;
import android.content.Context;
import android.location.Location;
import android.location.LocationListener;
import android.location.LocationManager;
import android.os.Bundle;

public class MyLocation {
    Timer timer1;
    LocationManager lm;
    LocationResult locationResult;
    boolean gps_enabled=false;
    boolean network_enabled=false;


    public boolean getLocation(Context context, LocationResult result)
    {
        //I use LocationResult callback class to pass location value from MyLocation to user code.
        locationResult=result;
        if(lm==null)
            lm = (LocationManager) context.getSystemService(Context.LOCATION_SERVICE);

        //exceptions will be thrown if provider is not permitted.
        try{gps_enabled=lm.isProviderEnabled(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER);}catch(Exception ex){}
        try{network_enabled=lm.isProviderEnabled(LocationManager.NETWORK_PROVIDER);}catch(Exception ex){}

        //don't start listeners if no provider is enabled
        if(!gps_enabled && !network_enabled)
            return false;

        if(gps_enabled)
            lm.requestLocationUpdates(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER, 0, 0, locationListenerGps);
        if(network_enabled)
            lm.requestLocationUpdates(LocationManager.NETWORK_PROVIDER, 0, 0, locationListenerNetwork);
        timer1=new Timer();
        timer1.schedule(new GetLastLocation(), 90000);
        return true;
    }

    LocationListener locationListenerGps = new LocationListener() {
        public void onLocationChanged(Location location) {
            timer1.cancel();
            locationResult.gotLocation(location);
            lm.removeUpdates(this);
            lm.removeUpdates(locationListenerNetwork);
        }
        public void onProviderDisabled(String provider) {}
        public void onProviderEnabled(String provider) {}
        public void onStatusChanged(String provider, int status, Bundle extras) {}
    };

    LocationListener locationListenerNetwork = new LocationListener() {
        public void onLocationChanged(Location location) {
            timer1.cancel();
            locationResult.gotLocation(location);
            lm.removeUpdates(this);
            lm.removeUpdates(locationListenerGps);
        }
        public void onProviderDisabled(String provider) {}
        public void onProviderEnabled(String provider) {}
        public void onStatusChanged(String provider, int status, Bundle extras) {}
    };

    class GetLastLocation extends TimerTask {
        @Override
        public void run() {
             lm.removeUpdates(locationListenerGps);
             lm.removeUpdates(locationListenerNetwork);

             Location net_loc=null, gps_loc=null;
             if(gps_enabled)
                 gps_loc=lm.getLastKnownLocation(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER);
             if(network_enabled)
                 net_loc=lm.getLastKnownLocation(LocationManager.NETWORK_PROVIDER);

             //if there are both values use the latest one
             if(gps_loc!=null && net_loc!=null){
                 if(gps_loc.getTime()>net_loc.getTime())
                     locationResult.gotLocation(gps_loc);
                 else
                     locationResult.gotLocation(net_loc);
                 return;
             }

             if(gps_loc!=null){
                 locationResult.gotLocation(gps_loc);
                 return;
             }
             if(net_loc!=null){
                 locationResult.gotLocation(net_loc);
                 return;
             }
             locationResult.gotLocation(null);
        }
    }
    public void cancelTimer()
    {
        if(timer1!=null)
        {
         timer1.cancel();
         lm.removeUpdates(locationListenerGps);
         lm.removeUpdates(locationListenerNetwork);
        }
    }


    public static abstract class LocationResult{
        public abstract void gotLocation(Location location);
    }
}
```

The code in my main class:I have used a callback method so as to get the location object.

```
locationResult = new LocationResult(){
            @Override
            public void gotLocation(Location location){
                if(location!=null)
                {
                current_latitude=location.getLatitude();
                current_longitude=location.getLongitude();
                }
                if(location!=null&&!isLocationRecieved)
                {
                    MarinaJobKeys.user_viewing_jobs=true;
                    isLocationRecieved=true;

                    Handler handler = new Handler(Looper.getMainLooper());
                    handler.post(new Runnable(){

                        @Override
                        public void run() {
                            setcurrentlocation();

                        } 

                    });


                }
                else if(location==null)
                {
                    Toast.makeText(getActivity(),"NULL LOCATION RETURNED",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                }

            }

        };





 myLocation = new MyLocation();
            myLocation.getLocation(getActivity(), locationResult);
```

The issue is this:

The code works fine on an older device.But when i run on a new device , the onLocationchanged method in the Mylocation class never gets called.But in the older device it gets called instantly.How do i fix this issue?

EDIT:The issue got fixed on restarting the device.But why does it happen?

Comment: what do you mean by older and new devices

Comment: By older device i mean my phone android 2.6.By newer device i mean android 4.0+.The thing is when i debug on the newer device the onlocationchanged never gets called.

Comment: You are getting any error?

Comment: @Amy.No error.The issue is that The onlocationchanged method is never called for a newer device.

Comment: possible duplicate of [locationmanager.requestForLocation is not working in motorola backflip & samsung galaxy](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6496588/locationmanager-requestforlocation-is-not-working-in-motorola-backflip-samsung)

Comment: @Siddharth , in my case both providers are enabled.By the way,the issue got fixed when i rebooted the device.

Answer (score 0):

you have to enable location from setting.

please check [this link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21022297/fused-location-provider-doesnt-seem-to-use-gps-receiver).

```
go to setting --> Location Access --> turn on Location.
```

Comment: Both the providers are on.I am checking them as boolean variables in the code and both return true.